# Не открывается сообщение по ссылке

Tags: telegram, браузер

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу открыть сообщение из телеграм канала в браузере по ссылке на данное сообщение. Ошибка:
`Please open Telegram to view this post from`
и так со всеми сообщениями этого канала, сообщения не содержат аудио или видео.
Не могу понять в чём дело? подскажите, пожалуйста.

Спасибо.

ссылка на сообщение: https://t.me/cybersecuritytechnologies/2895

Специально для тех, кто в `танке` :)

Из приложения, которое установлено в ОС Windows...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее вставить скопированное в адресную строку браузера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть канал, из которого не удаётся так просмотреть сообщение в браузере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны положительно ответить на запрос открытия приложения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и после этого откроется канал с акцентом на пост:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не совсем то что мне нужно, я это и так знал.
если Вы внимательно прочитаете мой вопрос, то:
`не могу открыть сообщение из телеграм канала в браузере по ссылке на данное сообщение`,
меня интересует только браузер.
Это для того, чтобы можно было разместить чат канала на сайте.

Comment: Как должно открываться сообщение в браузере? web.telegram.org?

Comment: Не совсем, вот, откройте эту `ссылку`, у Вас появится сообщение одного из `каналов`. https://t.me/SecLabNews/9894

Comment: Это возможно почти из любого общедоступного канала в `Телегаме`, если Вы нажмёте `ПКМ` по `сообщению` и выберете пункт из контекстного меню - `Копировать ссылку на сообщение` и после чего скопированную ссылку вставляете в `адресную строку браузера` - `Enter` - появится `сообщение`.

Comment: к выше сказанному:
Данная ошибка: `Please open Telegram to view this post from` возникает если в сообщение содержится `аудиозапись` или `видеозапись`, которые можно просматривать только в `приложение Телеграмм`, но... приведённые мною сообщения не `содержат` такого контента. К сожалению, я ещё не получил ответа от `поддержки Телеграмма` :( ... жду

Comment: Из ваших комментариев всё ещё не ясно, как именно в браузере по ссылке должны открываться сообщения. Если ссылка открывается со смартфона и установлен мессенджер - переход в приложение, канал, к сообщению. Если это ПК - запрос на открытие, приложение, канал, к сообщению.

Comment: Да как может быть не понятно :)) Я прикреплю к своему посту скрин, как должно выглядеть.